# In Dart is there a quick way to convert int to double?

Tags: dart

Very simple issue. I have the useless class:

```dart
class Useless{
  double field;
  Useless(this.field);
}
```

I then commit the mortal sin and call `new Useless(0);`
In checked mode (which is how I run my tests) that blows up, because *'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'*.

Now, it works if I use `new Useless(0.0)` , but honestly I spend a lot of time correcting my tests putting .0s everywhere and I feel pretty dumb doing that.

As a temporary measure I rewrote the constructor as:

```dart
    class Useless{
      double field;
      Useless(num input){
          field = input.toDouble();
      }
    }
```

But that's ugly and I am afraid slow if called often. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a double? Can't you just use `num` everywhere?

Comment: Following the Dart style guide: "PREFER using double or int instead of num for parameter type annotations in performance sensitive code"

Comment: This doesnt look like performance sensitive code to me. I think you should decide if you need a general number or if you really need int or double and then you should change all your code to be num, int or double.

Comment: @Robert Using `int` and `double` instead of `num` is better for conveying intention. Why stop at using `num`? We can just make all variables `dynamic` and get rid of all strong typing annoyances in one strike...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[In Dart 2.1](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-1-improved-performance-usability-9f55fca6f31a), integer literals may be directly used where `double` is expected. (See https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34355.)

Note that this is syntactic sugar and applies only to *literals*. `int` *variables* still won't be automatically promoted to `double`, so code like:

```dart
double reciprocal(double d) => 1 / d;

int x = 42;
reciprocal(x);
```

would fail, and you'd need to do:

```dart
reciprocal(x.toDouble());
```

Answer (score 199):

Simply `toDouble()`

Example:

```
int intVar = 5;
double doubleVar = intVar.toDouble();
```

---

Thanks to @jamesdlin who actually gave this answer in a comment to my previous answer...

Answer (score 47):

You can also use:

```
int x = 15;
double y = x + .0;
```

Comment: I found this answer most useful when I wanted to cast from a Map<String, dynamic> where the value could already be a map:  `(map['length'] == null) ? null : map['length'] + .0`

Comment: i had to do then when parsing HTTP json response. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is also valid for when you want a const value whereas `.toDouble()` is not

Answer (score 18):

use toDouble() method.
For e.g.:

```
int a = 10
print(a.toDouble) 
//or store value in a variable and then use
double convertedValue = a.toDouble()
```

Answer (score 7):

From this attempt:

```
class Useless{
  double field;
  Useless(num input){
    field = input.toDouble();
  }
}
```

You can use the [parse method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/double/parse.html) of the `double class` which takes in a string.

```
class Useless{
  double field;
  Useless(num input){
    field = double.parse(input.toString()); //modified line
  }
}
```

A more compact way of writing the above class using constructor's initialisers is:

```
class Useless{
  double _field;
  Useless(double field):_field=double.parse(field.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since all divisions in flutter result to a double, the easiest thing I did to achieve this was just to divide the integer value with 1:
i.e.
`int x = 15;`
`double y = x /1;`

Answer (score 4):

There's no better way to do this than the options you included :(

I get bitten by this lots too, for some reason I don't get any warnings in the editor and it just fails at runtime; mighty annoying :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a combination:

```
static double checkDouble(dynamic value) {
  if (value is String) {
    return double.parse(value);
  } else if (value is int) {
    return 0.0 + value;
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can cast from int to double
`int a = 2;`
`double b = a*1.0;`