# When to use num in Dart

Tags: dart

I am new to Dart and I can see Dart has `num` which is the superclass of `int` and `double` (and only those two, since it's a compile time error to subclass `num` to anything else).

So far I can't see any benefits of using `num` instead of `int` or `double`, are there any cases where `num` is better or even recommended? Or is it just to avoid thinking about the type of the number so the compiler will decide if the number is an `int` or a `double` for us?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One benefit for example 
before Dart 2.1 :

suppose you need to define a double var like,

```
double x ;
```

if you define your x to be a double, when you assign it to its value, you have to specify it  say for example 9.876.

```
x = 9.876;
```

so far so good.

Now you need to assign it a value like say 9

you can't code it like this

```
x = 9;  //this will be error before dart 2.1
```

so you need to code it like

```
x = 9.0;
```

but if you define x as num

you can use

```
x = 9.0;
```

and

```
x = 9;
```

so it is a convenient way to avoid these type mismatch errors between integer and double types in dart.

both will be valid.

this was a situation before Dart 2.1 but still can help explain the concept

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417782/in-dart-is-there-a-quick-way-to-convert-int-to-double) may be related

Comment: So no benefits after Dart 2.1?

Comment: I don't think so, But I can not find practical use situation in my mind for now :)

Comment: In your example, `9` will be interpreted as the double `9.0`, but I'm not sure if `num` does that too. One situation where `num` can be used is for Javascript interop, since JS doesn't differentiate. Considering Dart was originally designed as a replacement for JS (but gave up on that idea a few years ago), it may have been included just for that purpose.

Comment: @JacobPhillips num will interpret 9 as int 9 that is the purpose of num and that is why its mix type. and I think you are right about Dart and JS.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is useful to anyone, but I just ran into a case where I needed `num` in a way.

I defined a utility function like this:

```dart
T maximumByOrNull<T, K extends Comparable<K>>(Iterable<T> it, K key(T),) {
  return it.isEmpty
      ? null
      : it.reduce((a, b) => key(a).compareTo(key(b)) > 0 ? a : b);
}
```

And invoking it like this…

```dart
eldest = maximumByOrNull(students, (s) => s.age);
```

… caused trouble when `age` is an `int`, because `int` itself does not implement `Comparable<int>`.

So Dart cannot infer the type `K` in the invocation to `maximumByOrNull`.

However, `num` *does* implement `Comparable<num>`. And if I specified:

```dart
eldest = maximumByOrNull(students, (s) => s.age as num);         // this
eldest = maximumByOrNull<Student, num>(students, (s) => s.age);  // or this
```

the complaint went away.

---

Bottom line: it seems `num` implements `Comparable` when `int` and `double` do not, themselves, and sometimes this causes trouble for generic functions.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a use case when it is useful.
My app stores weight, which was originally defined as a `double`.

When using with a local database (sqlite) it works fine, since sqlite handles integer and real types.

However, when I converted my app to use Firestore database, I ran into issues with all my `double` fields. If a decimal value is stored everything works fine. However, when the weight happens to be a whole number, Firestore returns it as an `int` and suddenly type errors - `int` is not a subtype of type `double` - start to appear.

In the above scenario changing the `double` fields and variables to `num` was a quite simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

A good use case of `num` are extensions that work with `int` **and** `double`.

As an example I include the extension `MinMax` on `List<num>` that provides the getters `min` and `max`.

```
extension MinMax on List<num>{
  /// Returns the maximum value or `null` if the list is empty.
  num get max {
    return (isNotEmpty)
        ? fold<num>(0, (prev, current) => (prev > current) ? prev : current)
        : null;
  }

  /// Returns the minimum value or `null` if the list is empty.
  num get min {
    return (isNotEmpty)
        ? fold<num>(0, (prev, current) => (prev < current) ? prev : current)
        : null;
  }
}
```

Using the extension above one can access the min/max values without a need to create specific implementations for the classes `int` and `double`.

```
void main() {
  final a = <int>[1,3,5];
  final b = <double>[ 0.5, 0.8, -5.0];
  print(a.min);
  print(b.max);
  
}
```