# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' flutter

Tags: flutter, stack

```
class H extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
   child:   stack(context, 'assets/sbg.png', 80, 111, 58, 215, 'assets/logo.png', 'title', 'subtitle'),
    );
  }
}

//////////


 Widget stack(BuildContext context,image, left,top,height,width,logo,title,subtitle){
  return Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
                left: createSize( left, context),
                top: createSize(top, context),
                height: createSize(height, context),
                width: createSize(width, context),
                child: Column(children: [
                   Image.asset(logo),
               Text(title,style: TextStyle(),),Text(subtitle),
                ],),
                
               ),
            Container(
              height: createSize(447, context),
              width: createSize(375, context),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(image), fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
}
```

I have this issue on my flutter application.
i am always getting an error like this "type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast" , what error i have made here?
The following _TypeError was thrown building SignIn(dirty):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'.

Comment: Please update your post and show us the *LINE THE ERROR OCCURS ON*.  ALSO: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163726/421195) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toDouble.html)

Comment: You are right, I agree. But if you look at his code he uses his own functions to build widgets and he probably set the arguments to be of type `double` so he would have to write `.toDouble()` on every number he hardcodes into his function calls. That is very practical. So adding `.0` to every number or changing argument type to `int` would be a more logical solution in this case. Please reconsider the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error you could just add `.0` to every number you have in your code. For example if you have `500` turn it into `500.0`.

This happens because `500` is an `int` and `500.0` is a `double` and those are different types.

`int` is used to store whole numbers like: `500`.

`double` is used to store numbers with decimal points: like: `1.618`.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider clicking on the green checkmark to mark it as correct so it can help other people in the future. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Okay. I did it. Thank you :)